# Getting error with jsf2 "...backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory" in Grails plugin project

Tags: grails, plugins, jsf-2

I am running Grails 2.01, and Tomcat in dev mode (normal STS developer download).

I tried to run the jsf plugin but it wouldn't work in Grails 2.

So for instruction for me I've tried to build my own local plugin, build it as native v2 plugin and and learn about plugin projects on the way. I have been deconstructing (slowly) the Grails jsf2 plugin and rebuilding it the hard way, bit by bit, and learn as I go.

My problem is as follows - I've built my plugin locally - called it 'wwjsf'.

I've completed the doWithWebDescriptor closure - but when I run the plugin I get an error with - and the server won't render an .xhtml files - any such request gives same error.

I have included the latest Mojarra jsf 2.1.7 api/impl files into my build path for the project - here's the error on default Tomcat embedded in Grails 2.01.

```
Message: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.
Line | Method
->> 1008 | getFactory in javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    343 | getFactory in javax.faces.FactoryFinder
|    302 | init . . . in javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
|    303 | innerRun   in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    138 | run . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|    886 | runTask    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run . . .  in     ''
^    662 | run        in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-04-04 18:32:55,748 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR [localhost].[/wwjsf]  - Servlet    /wwjsf threw load() exception
Message: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.
Line | Method
->> 1008 | getFactory in javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    343 | getFactory in javax.faces.FactoryFinder
|    302 | init . . . in javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
|    303 | innerRun   in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    138 | run . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|    886 | runTask    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run . . .  in     ''
^    662 | run        in java.lang.Thread
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/wwjsf
```

I have done a dump of the web.xml as finalised in the closure to have a peek.  I looked up the error up on Google and it said you had to have the facesConfigureListener set - which I have, and I have checked the faces server element in the xml and I think it looks good.

In addition, I have put an empty faces-config.xml under the WEB-INF (I'll worry about how to create that in a project that uses the plugin later), and as some of the Google warnings said I have to have the jsf files in the WEB-INF/lib directory - I manually created that /lib and copied my jsf 2.1.7 api/impl jars into it as well for belt and braces.

How do I get rid of this error in the embedded Tomcat server?

Final web.xml config looks like:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    metadata-complete="true" version="2.5" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
   <display-name>/wwjsf-development-null</display-name>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
      <param-value>C:\Users\802518659\Documents\grails-workspace\wwjsf\web-app\WEB-INF\faces-config.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
      <param-value>server</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
      <param-value>com.softwood.grails.jsf.facelets.GrailsResourceResolver</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Production</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
      <param-value>wwjsf-development-null</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <filter>
     <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter>
     <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>characterEncodingFilter</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>urlMapping</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter>
     <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethod</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>grailsWebRequest</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethod</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>grailsWebRequest</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
       <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>urlMapping</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>-webAllowOthers</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dbconsole/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <description>
            Allows developers to view the intermediate source code, when they pass
            a spillGroovy argument in the URL.
            </description>
    <param-name>showSource</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>grails-errorhandler</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>grails-errorhandler</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/grails-errorhandler</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.dispatch</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.gsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/grails-errorhandler</location>
 </error-page>
 <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
       <taglib>
           <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
           <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/tags</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://grails.codehaus.org/tags</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/grails.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
 </web-app>
```

Answer (score 10):

When i got this error  (i use maven and embedded jetty alongside spring and jsf2), I added this on web.xml

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>
```

And the error was gone.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer sir. But why does this happen? How does this solution work?